# how to retain emoji using ruamel-yaml dump

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file that contains emojis in it, and I am looking to use ruamel-yaml to load this yaml, edit it, and then dump it back. The problem I am facing right now is that it does not retain the emoji, but rather the unicode string.

Here is my yaml file

```yaml
# filename: t.yml
text: "Docs "
```

And a snippet of the code

```py
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.width = 1024
yaml.encoding = "utf-8"

with open("t.yml") as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

And here is the output:

```
❯ python3 t.py
text: "Docs \U0001F4DA"
```

If I remove the `preserve_quotes` then the output is fine:

```
python3 t.py
text: Docs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the emitter code for double quoted scalars, the behaviour of which came under
scrutiny [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75631454/1307905)

Building on the answer there, a small additional change to `write_double_quoted` makes
it deal with Unicode characters above `\uFFFD`:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

class MyEmitter(ruamel.yaml.emitter.Emitter):
    def write_double_quoted(self, text, split=True):
        if self.root_context:
            if self.requested_indent is not None:
                self.write_line_break()
                if self.requested_indent != 0:
                    self.write_indent()
        self.write_indicator(u'"', True)
        start = end = 0
        while end <= len(text):
            ch = None
            if end < len(text):
                ch = text[end]
            if (
                ch is None
                or ch in u'"\\\x85\u2028\u2029\uFEFF'
                or not (
                    u'\x20' <= ch <= u'\x7E'
                    or (
                        self.allow_unicode
                        and (
                            (u'\xA0' <= ch <= u'\uD7FF') or
                            (u'\uE000' <= ch <= u'\uFFFD') or
                            (u'\U00010000' <= ch <= u'\U0010FFFF')
                        )
                    )
                )
            ):
                if start < end:
                    data = text[start:end]
                    self.column += len(data)
                    if bool(self.encoding):
                        data = data.encode(self.encoding)
                    self.stream.write(data)
                    start = end
                if ch is not None:
                    if ch in self.ESCAPE_REPLACEMENTS:
                        data = u'\\' + self.ESCAPE_REPLACEMENTS[ch]
                    elif ch <= u'\xFF':
                        data = u'\\x%02X' % ord(ch)
                    elif ch <= u'\uFFFF':
                        data = u'\\u%04X' % ord(ch)
                    else:
                        data = u'\\U%08X' % ord(ch)
                    self.column += len(data)
                    if bool(self.encoding):
                        data = data.encode(self.encoding)
                    self.stream.write(data)
                    start = end + 1
            if (
                0 < end < len(text) - 1
                and (ch == u' ' or start >= end)
                and self.column + (end - start) > self.best_width
                and split
            ):
                # data = text[start:end] + u'\\'  # <<< replaced with following two lines
                need_backquote = text[end] == u' ' and (len(text) > end) and text[end+1] == u' '
                data = text[start:end] + (u'\\' if need_backquote else u'')
                if start < end:
                    start = end
                self.column += len(data)
                if bool(self.encoding):
                    data = data.encode(self.encoding)
                self.stream.write(data)
                self.write_indent()
                self.whitespace = False
                self.indention = False
                if text[start] == u' ':
                    if not need_backquote:
                        # remove leading space it will load from the newline
                        start += 1 
                    # data = u'\\'    # <<< replaced with following line
                    data = u'\\' if need_backquote else u''
                    self.column += len(data)
                    if bool(self.encoding):
                        data = data.encode(self.encoding)
                    self.stream.write(data)
            end += 1
        self.write_indicator(u'"', False)


file_in = Path('t.yaml')
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Emitter = MyEmitter
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.width = 1024
data = yaml.load(file_in)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
# filename: t.yaml
text: "Docs "
```

The added range test under `self.allow_unicode`:

```
                        (u'\U00010000' <= ch <= u'\U0010FFFF')
```

is what makes the difference.

Please note:

- `yaml.encoding = 'utf-8'` is the default, so you don't need to set that
- if you are working with UTF-8 files you should open them as binary (`open(..., 'rb')`)
- the recommended extension for files containing YAML documents
  has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006. The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML
  based, and at least as old as YAML.

Comment: I had a good feeling when I posted this question last night, that I would have an answer today. Thank you very much, I see you are very active answering questions here and I appreciate that. (Re. using `.yml` I normally use .yaml though I wasn't aware of the context you added, I used .yml cause I was doing a quick run to provide context without using my actual file.)

Comment: on another note, is this emitter, something that can be built-in (or would make sense to have built-in), so that I can just call `yaml.emitter(yaml.UNICODE_EMITTER)` or something like that?

Comment: The emitter needs some context provided by the `YAML()` instance, so you cannot really call it seperately. This actual change should make it into a future release, but I am not sure when that will be made.